# Cannot see SQL statements when logging in Django 2.1.4

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.1

When trying to log SQL statements in Django I can see params, duration but not the SQL statement itself. The context parameter `sql` returns `None`

I am using MySQL as backend

Settings setup:

```py
DEBUG=True
...
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} SQL:{sql} {duration} params:{params}',
            'style': '{',
        }},
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django.db.backends': {
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
            },
        }
    }
```

Sample output:
`DEBUG SQL:None 0.036980390548706055 params:(1,)`

So I can the duration, the parameters but not the SQL statements. And I do not know why.

I have based my configuration on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django-db-backends

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During a long long search found out this is a bug in version **2.1.4** upgrading to **2.1.5** fixed the problem. I based this on this

https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/issues/1124

Checked and verified. Output after update:

`DEBUG SQL:SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED 0.035988569259643555 params:None`